# Making QI charging desk

Tags: wireless, charger, charging

I want to make my desk surface into a QI charger but I want a large surface so integrating a pd wont work.

Can I disassemble the charger and add multiple coils to it, or do I need to buy several chargers and keep them separate?

Answer (score 7):

Pick one location on your desk to use as a charger.

Combining multiple Qi coils into a larger charging "table" is a nontrivial task. Simply placing multiple separate chargers side by side will not work, as they will interfere with each other.

[Apple tried to create a product along these lines, and they failed.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirPower_(hardware)) It is unlikely that you will succeed where they did not.